# numpy.TooHardError with numpy.shares_memory function

Tags: python, numpy

Why does setting `max_work=numpy.MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS` for the `numpy.shares_memory` function give me this exception: `numpy.TooHardError: Exceeded max_work` ?

Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = x
print(np.shares_memory(x, y, max_work=np.MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS))
```

Comment: Tell us about the arrays that you are testing

Comment: I tested it with a simple `arange(10)` array and got this error.  `np.MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS` has value `0`, the default `EXACT` is `-1`.  Since `shares_memory` is compiled code, it is hard to deduce what is going on, and the documentation doesn't help.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah the documentation doesn't say much. Can you explain what max_work is though? and what do the values it takes mean?